# How to control website component showing?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, css, html

I'm working with a shopping cart developed by PHP. I wanna know how to control a web component display or hide. Under the header displays xx Hour xx Min xx Sec,When the time counting down, show something. When the time ends,hide something(I don't know if it's deleted or hidden)and display other content.English is not my mother tongue. Maybe I don't express myself clearly. Sorry for that. Archive this function on the server-side with php or browser-side with js or something like that? Please give me some suggestion. Hope get your reply. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far? StackOverflow is not meant to write the code *for you*

Comment: Sorry for that. I have no idea to implementing it. I just need some inspiration. I don't have to get some code. I just wanna know how it works. Thank you for your reply thajeztah.

Comment: it's not a good idea to begin your learning by doing 10 different things all at once and try to get it right just from a single question on a forum. You must break down your question into its components (each component will have enough tutorials online.. even in your native language).. then you put those pieces back together and see if it works.. if it doesn't, then you must narrow down your problem and ask us that part of your problem here.. that's how it works.